# Creat VBA Dictionary Entry When Criteria Is Met

Tags: excel, dictionary, syntax, vba

I am new to VBA Dictionaries.  What I am trying to do is evaluate each row of a sheet.  If the value in Column J is "100", then I want to create a key/item entry into the dictionary.  If any other value is in Column J, I do not want the entry to be created and for the macro to look at the next row of data.

I currently have the code below:

```
Dim x, x2, y, y2()
Dim i As Long
Dim dict As Object
Dim LastRowTwo As Long, shtOrders As Worksheet, shtReport As Worksheet

Set shtOrders = Worksheets("Orders")
Set shtReport = Worksheets("Mapping")
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

With shtReport
    LastRow = .Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    x = .Range("G2:G" & LastRow).Value
    x2 = .Range("I2:I" & LastRow).Value

   Set SelectionRNG = Worksheets("Mapping").Range("G2:J" & LastRow)

For Each rngrow In SelectionRNG.Rows

If rngrow.Cells(1, 4) = "100" Then
 dict.Item(x(i, 1)) = x2(i, 1)

End If    
 Next
  End With
```

I know that this line:

```
dict.Item(x(i, 1)) = x2(i, 1)
```

Is where my problem is.  I have used that syntax in the code below and it works fine:

```
    For i = 1 To UBound(x, 1)
   dict.Item(x(i, 1)) = x2(i, 1)
   Next i
```

I am stuck on how to change the syntax of either my "rngrow code" to add a dictionary entry without using the "i" or to adjust the code directly above to include an IF statement to check the value in column J (and only create an entry if J = 100 for the row currently being assessed.

If the code above was not clear, the key would be in Column G and the item would be in column I.  (I later lookup Column G and retrieve column I's value.)

As I said, I am new to this, so I appreciate any help!

Cheers!

Comment: Maybe replace `i` with `rngrow.Row - 1`

Comment: Argh! I had suggested an alternative to `rngrow.Row - 1`, then deleted it because I thought the cells were on different sheets, but now realise that they aren't.  So, I'll suggest it again - you can use `rngrow.Cells(1, 1).Value` instead of `x(i, 1)` and `rngrow.Cells(1, 3).Value` instead of `x2(i, 1)`.

Comment: @YowE3K Thanks for both those solutions, The `rngrow.row-1` replacing `i` works -- Your solution below also works and I think is slightly more transparent so I'm applying that to my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would get rid of `rngrow` and just loop through rows 2 to `LastRow`:

```
Dim i As Long
Dim dict As Object
Dim LastRow As Long, shtReport As Worksheet

Set shtReport = Worksheets("Mapping")
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

With shtReport
    LastRow = .Range("G" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To LastRow
        If .Cells(i, "J") = "100" Then
            dict.Item(.Cells(i, "G").Value) = .Cells(i, "I").Value
        End If
    Next
End With
```